# problem with wget in vps

Tags: server, wget, vps, virtualmin

i install ubuntu-server 12.4 on my vps. i want to install virtualmin. when i trying to download **[virtualmin]install.sh** with wget, i saw this:

```
:/tmp# wget http://software.virtualmin.com/gpl/scripts/install.sh

--2013-11-27 23:26:03--  http://software.virtualmin.com/gpl/scripts/install.sh
Resolving software.virtualmin.com (software.virtualmin.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address `software.virtualmin.com'
```

what's the problem? and how can i fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this issue is raised due  to DNS-related problem. You need to check the config file `/etc/resolv.conf`. It should contains entries like:

```
nameserver your.dns1.server.ip
nameserver your.dns2.server.ip
```

check if there is any thing strange in that..

Comment: Thanks,wget is working now. i added "nameserver 8.8.8.8" in "/etc/resolv.conf"